# ASC and DESC conditions in SOAP API magento 1.9

Tags: magento, soap

I have rewrited Api model of Magento Core (M1.9) and want to test how it works. It returns too may records and I want to set conditions like in Sql "order BY Desc|Asc" and "LIMIT" in my tests. But i dont know where should i place mentioned conditions. 
Here is my code for tests:

```
$username = 'testapi';
$apikey= 'password';

$client = new Zend_XMLRPC_Client('https://www.magentohost.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc');
$session = $client->call('login', array($username, $apikey));
$filters = array(
    array(
        'category_id' => 163,
        'internal_rating' => 6
    //array('product_id'=>'Order by ASC')
));

try {
    $message = $client->call('call', array($session, 'catalog_product.list', $filters));

        var_dump($message);

} catch (Exception $fault) {
    echo $fault->getMessage();
}
```

I will be appreciated for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to test the code below:

```
$filters = array(
    array(
        'category_id'     => 163,
        'internal_rating' => 6, 
        'order'           => 'product_id',
        'dir'             => 'asc',
        'limit'           => 100    
));
```

I haven't tested it by myself. I took the format of filter parameters from the link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/get_filters.html
Maybe it will work for your case, too.

Comment: Thank You Aleks. I tried this way before and it is was unsuccesful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite this class and override items function 
class = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api
function = items

```
  public function items($filters = null, $store = null, $extra = [])
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

        if(isset($extra["cur_page"])) {
            $collection->setCurPage($extra["cur_page"]);
        }
        if(isset($extra["page_size"])) {
            $collection->setPageSize($extra["page_size"]);
        }
        if(isset($extra["order"])) {
            $collection->setOrder($extra["order"]["field"], $extra["order"]["type"]);
        }
```

then you can call it by

```
$filters = []; 
$extra = ["cur_page"=>1,"page_size"=>"3","order"=>["field"=>"name", "type"=>"desc"]];

$result= $proxy->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.list',[$filters,null,$extra]);
```

Comment: Thank You HAKIM for answer, I didnt try your solution but I think it will work. I solve my problem as i described in my answer and it was simillar way as you gave. It is interesting to know your opinion about mine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to transfer the parameters limit,dir, order into url request by GET method like:

```
$client = new 
Zend_XMLRPC_Client('https://www.magentohost.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc?
limit=1&dir=desc&order=created_at');

$session = $client->call('login', array($username, $apikey));
$filters = array(
array(
    'category_id' => 174
));
```

And in rewrited class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api method item

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('content_downloaded')
                    ;
    if (isset($_GET['order']) && isset($_GET['dir'])){
        $order = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET['order']));
        $dir = (strtoupper($_GET['dir']) == 'DESC' ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        $collection->setOrder($order, $dir);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['limit'])){
        $limit = intval($_GET['limit']);
        $collection->getSelect()->limit($limit);
    }
```

And it gave googd tests.It is similar Solution as HAKIM suggested.